# Draw Graph for Pearson's Correlation Algo

Tags: algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, graph-visualization, pearson

I am using Pearson's Correlation Algorithm to find dependency between two variables. This algorithm return a value between -1 and 1, which tell relation b/w two variables. 
My problem is that i want to visualize output graphically, not discrete value i.e. draw graph, which will tell the relationship between two variables. 
Please tell me if someone knows about it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to represent a value between -1 and 1 graphically.
One option is to have it color-coded, e.g. either on a heat-scale ('red' is 1), or on a black-white gradient.

Somehow I have the feeling there is more to your question, like maybe you want to show relations of more than two variable at a time? For this you could draw a graph (e.g. with graphviz) and have the correlation value as the 'weight' factor of the edges between nodes (nodes are the variables, edges the PC value).

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is create a scatter plot. If you have one variable Y with measurements X_1 .. X_N and another Y with Y_1 .. Y_N, simply draw all the points (X_i, Y_i).